# Normalize Angular 2 Tags

Tags: discussion

Angular 2.x is in Developer Preview and is very different than Angular 1.x (Current prevalent tag is angularjs on stackoverflow).  To help those who want support with this new version (both getting and giving support), I recommend normalizing these tags on stackoverflow.  To date, there are many tags including:

- angular2
- angularjs-2.0
- angularjs-2

Angular2 is currently the most popular even though I like angularjs-2 more to be in line with angularjs

Comment: Except the new Angular is actually just called Angular (no JS or version numbers) so these suggestions aren't terribly appropriate. Either way, there's already been a couple other discussions around this and the other Angular related tags.